# Wrong cells update in UITableView while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I have a simple app which shows public transport on the map. It has a feature to enable/disable display specific transport routes on map. It is a list in `UITableView`, in each cell there is a name of route and a check sign which displays if a route is enabled or disabled. The problem is when I tap on the bottom cell of list (so, the check sign appears, so the route is enabled), and then I scroll up and down the list several times, after that the check sign on previously tapped cell disappears, I don't know why. But though the check sign disappeared, the appropriate route is enabled, there is know problem of it. Looks like the problem is in my realization of `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method of my `UITableViewController` inherited class. Here it is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    FilterTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    BOOL isChecked;
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        cell.routeLabel.text = trollRoutes[indexPath.row]; // array of route names
        cell.directionLabel.text = trollDirections[indexPath.row]; // one more array of route names
        cell.isChecked = trollCheck[indexPath.row];
        // trollCheck is array of BOOL values, each value means if route is enabled or disabled
        cell.checkedLabel.text = cell.isChecked ? @"✓" : @"";
    }
    // same for trams, we're reading values from other arrays, it display first, and there are NO problems with it
    else if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.routeLabel.text = tramRoutes[indexPath.row];
        cell.directionLabel.text = tramDirections[indexPath.row];
        cell.isChecked = tramCheck[indexPath.row];
        cell.checkedLabel.text = cell.isChecked ? @"✓" : @"";
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The values of `trollCheck` array don't change while I scroll the table. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: So what is the difference between the second section and the others

Comment: I think that your sections are throwing you off. Can you do it in one section for debugging. When debugging, what is the value of `indexPath.row` for the trollCheck each time

Comment: I've debugged `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in situation when my trouble appear (the route is enabled but the check sign become unchecked after scrolling). So, the value of array element which related to problem cell is still YES, so the cell must remain checked. I have 2 sections - one for trolleybuses, other for trams, the tram section is first, so the code for it is the same, and there are NO problems with it.